# Cite a book in general and then a chapter in particular

Tags: publications, citations, thesis, computer-science, bibtex

The question is in the context of a paper and a thesis in the area of computational science, computer science and chemistry. I manage my references with Mendeley, and import them into a LaTeX file using Bibtex.

In the introduction, I cite a book about the general approach used in that research project. Later on, in a section about methods and computer implementation, I'd like to refer to the specific chapter in that book from where some algorithms were taken. (Twice for two different chapters actually.)

**What's the correct way to cite that book in general and then the chapter in particular?**

(I also asked this question [here](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/36281/cite-a-book-in-general-and-then-a-chapter-in-particular?noredirect=1#comment56698_36281), but it was recommended that I better ask in this community.)

Comment: What does it say in the Harvard approach or APA? Which do you follow?

Comment: In math the way to go would be "In [X] the authors say blabla... In [X, chapter 4] they prove this great lemma and in [X, chapter 18] they define these objects..." where X is the whole book.

Answer (score 3):

As Najib Idrissi commented, I have also similar approach in my field of Computer Science.

In one of my paper, I had to cite the book twice in the following way.

"The application domains have expanded in various horizons considering the applicability of the this approach and has led the community to look for problems in .... \cite{FullBook}. One of the prinicipal advantage of using such an approach lies in its computational complexity which has been found to be O(n^2).\cite[Chapter 2, Proof:3.2]{Book}"